# if else statement hierarchy JS

Tags: javascript, class, if-statement, hierarchy

I have 3 possible class combinations that can be applied to an element, for our sake the classes are

```
".a" and ".b"
```

sometimes both `.a` and `.b` can be applied or sometimes just `.a` and sometimes no classes at all. I want to write an if statement that catches all 3 possible combinations for example

```
if (node.hasClass("a")){
//do something
}else if(node.hasClass("a") && node.hasClass("b")){
//do something different
}else{
//some something else all together
};
```

But right now this if statement is not working, any suggestions?

Thanks!

** hasClass(); is a YUI3 method

Comment: Switch your else if order. You will never get to second else if because it will always be satisfied by the first if condition. Switch the order of conditions.
`
if(node.hasClass("a") && node.hasClass("b")){
}else if(node.hasClass("a")){
}else{}
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always need to "catch" the most restrictive case first. So change your logic to:

```
if (node.hasClass("a") && node.hasClass("b")){
//do something
}else if(node.hasClass("a")){
//do something different
}else{
//some something else all together
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original code doesn't work because if the node has class `a` (regardless of whether or not it also has class `b`), it will enter the first block, and never check the other conditions.

Try this instead:

```
if (node.hasClass("a")) {
    if(node.hasClass("b")) {
        // has a and b
    } else {
        // has a only
    }
} else {
    // does not have a
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(node.hasClass("a") && node.hasClass("b"))
{
    //both .a and .b
}
else if(node.hasClass("a"))
{
    //only .a
}
else if(node.hasClass("b"))
{
    //only .b
}
else
{
    //neither
}
```